# ASP.NET tab control with custom tab shapes

Tags: asp.net, tabs

I need to create ASP.NET tabs with each tab looking like a triangle (similar to OneNote tabs). are there any available tab controls that support this out of the box?

if it's not in ASP.NET world, but in js (like extJS or jQuery) I'll take that and just adopt it. I know those libraries are advanced, but I don't know if I they can do what I need easily.

Answer (score 0):

check out Matt Berseth AjaxControlToolkit TabContainer Theme Gallery
[http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/ajaxcontroltoolkit_tabcontaine.html][1]

[1]: http://AjaxControlToolkit TabContainer Theme Gallery